# Link two sharepoint columns together

Tags: sharepoint, list

I have two lists in SharePoint. One is a Server/Device list, the other is an IP Address list. I would like to pre-populate the IP Address list, and then, on the server/device list select the IP address(s) assigned to that server.

After that, I'd like the "Device" column on the IP Address list to reflect which device is using it.

Is it possible to do this without having to manually set the device on the IP Address list? I want it to automatically update based upon what the row device has set.

Comment: It sound like you should go with some sort of lookup column. I´m not sure if you have looked in to that already that´s why I´m adding this "answer" as a comment instead of a "real" answer. If you need help with a lookup column, let me know and I´ll add a "real" answer and try to help you out further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Step 1 - Use lookup in Device list
  that looks up IPs from IP Address
  list.
- Step 2 - Create a Event Handler Code for Device List that listens to 
  the item updated event

  public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
- Step 3 - When list item      in
  Device List has updated, your event handler (created in step 2) will assign that value to the matched
  item in IP Address List

James